# The correlation coefficient

Tags: correlation

Suppose that the R.V. $X$ and $Y$ lie on the line parallel to the $x$ axis.
Then their correlation must be $1$ and $-1$ at the same time!
What's wrong with the degenerate case here ?

Comment: What kind of correlation are you referring to and what is the formula for it?

Comment: The statement in your question is not right. The sample (Pearson) correlation $r_{X,Y}$ is undefined if either the $X_i$s or the $Y_i$s have zero variance. Similarly for population correlation $ρ_{X,Y}.$ // In your example the variance of $Y$ is $0.$

Answer (score 2):

Three examples in R. With two sample correlations and three scatterplots.

```
set.seed(2020)
x = rnorm(50, 100, 15)
y1 = rnorm(50, 0, .01)  # Indep of x
y2 = 2 + .005*x         # Exactly linear in x
y3 = rep(2, 50)         # All 50 obs. are exactly 2

cor(x,y1); cor(x,y2); cor(x,y3)
[1] -0.06064351   # Essentially 0
[1] 1             # Exactly 1
[1] NA            # Undefined
  Warning message:
  In cor(x, y3) : the standard deviation is zero

par(mfrow=c(1,3))
 plot(x, y1, ylim=c(-1,3), main="Independent")
 plot(x, y2, ylim=c(-1,3), main="Points on Line")
 plot(x, y3, ylim=c(-1,3), main="Undefined r")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

[image]